# iOS Mapkit test if at maximum zoom level

Tags: ios, zooming, mapkit

I have an app at which I want to only turn on certain functionality when the map I am displaying (via MKMapView).

Is there a way of determining if the map view is at max. zoom level, or do I need to put some sort of region threshold in and test against that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get to the max zoomlevel on iOS 7 MKMapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658329/how-to-get-to-the-max-zoomlevel-on-ios-7-mkmapview)

Comment: No, I don't believe it is. The wording of the question looks as if it does, but the answer does't address my specific problem, particularly as it appears to changes from iOS release to iOS release. I need a specific 'am I at max zoom level' test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5798112/2924596) points to [`MKMapViewZoom`](https://github.com/jdp-global/MKMapViewZoom) category that will return you current zoom level.

In [this article](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/) Troy Brant explains that map can have zoom levels from 0 to 20. It's true either for Google or for Apple maps, because both are in mercator projection. So the solution will work in iOS 5.x-7.x

You should check experimentally what zoom level (or range of them) fits to you needs.

Comment: #IvanRublev  Thanks for the link.  Great. That helped a lot